# rsync folder out of apache server in php

Tags: apache, ssh, exec, rsync

This command I can run in command line correctly.

```
>sshpass -p 'xxxx' rsync -rve ssh /var/www/html/my_profect/image server2@192.168.xxx.xxx:/var/www/html/project2
```

But I want to call this command from php page using `exec()`. but when i call from php page rsync wasn't moving any file and no error was given.

Comment: We cannot help with your issue if you don't post your php code...

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `passthru()` instead of `exec()` to get raw shell output.
2. Use `var_dump(passthru($command));` to view output.